# Multiple value to single key

Tags: python, python-2.6

I have an input file which contains `<name> <surname>` e.g.

```
Shankar Kale
Jitendra Shirke
Rajendra Bagwe
Mahendra Kale
```

I want to create dictionary which maps surnames to names like this:

```
{'Kale':['Shankar', 'Mahendra'], 'Bagwe':'Rajendra', 'Shirke':'Jitendra'}
```

Comment: Try saving names and surnames as 2D array, extract the unique 'surname' values, and you have your keys. Then iterate over the 'name' row and group entries by key.

Comment: Are there always two words in each line, or can there be multiple first names?

Comment: So just use a dictionary with lists as the values. And put the name part in the list

Comment: Yes there always two words in each line.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether there can be multiple first names, so this solution is going to cover that possibility. It assumes that the surname is always the last word in the line.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> with open('myfile', 'r') as names:
...      for line in names:
...          firstnames, lastname = line.strip().rpartition(' ')[::2] # or just line.split() if there are always two words in each line
...          d[lastname].append(firstnames)
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'Bagwe': ['Rajendra'], 'Kale': ['Shankar', 'Mahendra'], 'Shirke': ['Jitendra']})
```

If the lists with one element bother you, in Python2.7+ you can just issue:

```
>>> d = {k:(v if len(v)!=1 else v[0]) for k,v in d.iteritems()}
>>> d
{'Bagwe': 'Rajendra', 'Kale': ['Shankar', 'Mahendra'], 'Shirke': 'Jitendra'}
```

Since you are using Python2.6, you can do this:

```
d = dict([(k,(v if len(v)!=1 else v[0])) for k,v in d.iteritems()])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Default dict`

```
from collections import defaultdict
dictnames=defaultdict(list,{})
```

append your list

```
dictnames[<surname>].append(<first_name>)
```